# Oracle Application Container Cloud Service node.js auth set up

Tags: node.js, oracle, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I have this auth.js found on https://github.com/oracle/idm-samples/tree/master/idcs-sdk-sample-apps/nodejs
but when we deploy this Oracle Application Container Cloud Service. I know we need to change this "redirectURL": 'localhost:3000/callback' to call the function callback.
But im new in this, and i dont know to set this up. Any help is appreciated thanks.

```
 oracle: {
    "ClientId": '',
    "ClientSecret": '',
    "IDCSHost": '',
    "AudienceServiceUrl" : '',
    "TokenIssuer": 'https://identity.oraclecloud.com/',
    "scope": 'urn:opc:idm:t.user.me openid',
    "logoutSufix": '/sso/v1/user/logout',
    "redirectURL": 'localhost:3000/callback'
  }
```

How do i get the equivalent of local localhost:3000/callback to get my fucntion callback be called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please follow this tutorial:
https://apexapps.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=44785:112:0::::P112_CONTENT_ID:22661
or
the GitHub documentation: https://github.com/oracle/idm-samples/blob/master/idcs-sdk-sample-apps/nodejs/README.md

The Oracle-by-Example Tutorial uses this sample application. Both OBE and GitHub README.MD file explain how to update and run the sample application and also explains what the code does.
If your Node.js application does not answer in localhost:3000, you need to change the value of redirectURL property.

/callback is a route implemented by the sample application (follow the OBE to have the sample app updated with the correct pieces of code).

Comment: I already read and follow that code. But im getting 502 when I try to accesing the login via authentication. My app is deployed in Oracle cloud application container. Before when testing this code in local it runs as expected. Im thinking I need to configure something if i want to make this run in cloud container.

Comment: Wait I think i made an error. Ill update my code in monday. Thsnks